# Link href sem dominio

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa Noite pessoal.

Entrei em um site wordpress recentemente e notei um link dessa forma:

```
<a href="/carros/gol-0k" data-ss1560980866="1">Gol 0k</a>
```

Porem quando eu passava o mouse por cima do link, ele me mostrava a URL com o dominio completo na parte inferior do meu navegador:

```
<a href="www.carros.com/carros/gol-0k" data-ss1560980866="1">Gol 0k</a>
```

Fiquei curiosa e tentei implementar aqui só que não consegui. Como seria fazer isso, alguem já fez algo assim? Acho que não é JV.

Comment: Apenas o navegador acrescenta a URL completa no link quando vc passa o mouse, por se tratar de um subdiretório ou uma página do site.

Comment: Aqui tem uma boa explicação sobre esse assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392423/o-que-s%C3%A3o-relative-paths-quando-se-trata-de-links-de-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o#392427

Answer (score 0):

Amanda, essa função é dada pelo navegador em si, não pelo código do elemento `<a>`

Testei no FireFox e no Chrome, funciona:

```html
<a href="https://electronic.perina.net/">Passe o mouse AQUI</a>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Como o Ian falou, essa é uma função do navegador.

Acontece que a url "/carros/gol-0k" é chamada de **relativa**. Ela não depende do domínio e, se esse for alterado, não influencia na referência.

A url "www.carros.com/carros/gol-0k" é **absoluta**. Se o domínio mudar de "www.carros.com" pra "www.carros.com.br", a referência não funciona mais.