# Por que alguns links não informam o domínio ou o protocolo?

Tags: link, navegação

Gostaria de saber mais sobre links relativos de navegação e também gostaria de saber quais os prós e contras de utilizá-los.

Por exemplo, existem links que não informam o domínio e não informam o protocolo.

```
<a href="/home">Home</a> <!-- Não informa o domínio -->
<a href="//dominio.com/home</a> <!-- Não informa o protolocolo -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o nome diz ele é relativo (em relação a alguma coisa)

Imagine que as pastas de um site tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
/  (aqui a raiz do projeto)
css/
   estilos.css
imagens/
   logo.png
   icones/
       usuario.jpg
```

No seu arquivo "estilos.css" você quer criar um estilo onde o fundo seja imagem, a "logo.png" por exemplo.  Algo assim:

```
.estiloFundo { background-image: (logo.png) }
```

Isso não iria funcionar a princípio, porque na pasta onde está o arquivo "estilos.css", não existe o arquivo "logo.png".
Usando o caminho absoluto, precisaria saber o dns de onde está armazenado, suponha "http://meusite.com/aplicacao/imagens/logo.png".

Mas se mudar o dns ou algo mais no nome vai invalidar seu css, por isso podemos usar um caminho relativo.

Ou seja, "em relação à pasta "css", a imagem está um nível acima, depois na pasta imagens", ou seja, o caminho relativo seria "../imagens/logo.png", ou "em relação à pasta css, a pasta imagens está na **raiz** da estrutura", então o caminho relativo seria "/imagens/logo.png", portanto poderia ficar assim os caminhos relativos (à pasta onde está o estilos.css):

```
.estiloFundo { background-image: (../imagems/logo.png) }
.estiloFundo { background-image: (/imagems/logo.png) }
```

Usei um exemplo de imagem, mas pode ser qualquer recurso, links de arquivos html (páginas) por exemplo, algo como:

```
<a href="../contato/faleconosco.html">
```

A principal vantagem é não ter de saber o caminho absoluto, ou seja, todo o link do recurso que ser acessar.
Contra? Não consigo pensar em nenhum, comparando com a outra possibilidade, que é usar o caminho absoluto. Isso claro, usando dentro do seu site, se for um link para outro site tem de ser o caminho absoluto obviamente.